# findarray in mongodb and output to array in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have an array  inside a collection in mongodb as per below.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53dbb05fa976627439d43884"),
"employee" : [ 
    {
        "date" : "1986-03-10"

    }, 
    {
        "date" : "1986-12-11"

    }
    ]
    }
```

Now I want to find all distinct date and output it to array in nodejs format.

```
var collection = db.collection('employee');
collection.distinct('employee.date').toArray(function(err, docsa) {

console.log(docsa);

});

};
```

The problem is I will receive the following error, but those collection.distinct command can be run on mongodb.Anyhow I can avoid the error ?

```
 TypeError: Cannot call method 'toArray' of undefined
```

Or is there any way I can use collection.find() to get the same output?

Answer (score 1):

you try `collection.distinct('employee.data')`, on a collection called 'employee'. I believe you want :

```
collection.distinct('date')
```

Comment: opss Yes..typo error..its corrected..basically it's still the same error wrt to collection.distinct